# Smoothly interpolating between functions to create a bouncing wave

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How can I create a function which allows me to control the roundness of a wave so I can transition between an Round Wave -> Linear Wave -> Inverted Round wave?

I've made a function which creates a Bounce wave, but I feel there may be a more effective way of writing this. You can see in the picture below, if I pass the function a Smoothness value of -1 it will be inverted, 0 will be linear, and 1.0 will create the round wave. Any value between those will just be a transition between.

[image]

You'll see in the function below I'll be passing the following properties to the function...

> waveWidth: controls the wide of a single wave
>   minVal: starting position of the wave on the Y axis
>   maxVal: controls the overall height of the wave, subtracting the minVal
>   numSamples: the number of points to plot along the curve
>   smoothness: 'not implemented yet' but would control whats described above

```
fn BuildBounceArc waveWidth:10 minVal:0 maxVal:10 numSamples:20 smoothness:1.0 =
    (
        for i = 0 to numSamples do
        (
            ang = i * 180.0 / numSamples
            posZ = abs(sin(ang)) * (maxVal - minVal) + minVal
            posX = 1.0 * i / numSamples * waveWidth

            -- The line below is for plotting the points visually
            --point pos:[posX, 0, posZ] size:.5 wirecolor:green name:("ang_" + ang as string)
        )
    )
```

**Update:**

I've corrected the initial function which creates the outer arc. If you guys can help.me create the yellow inner arc I can figure out the rest no problem. Because if I have both arcs I would just use a percentage to weight the point position between the two arcs.

```
numSteps = 20
height = 15.0 --radius
width = 30.0 --radius
smoothness = .5

delete objects

for i = 0 to numSteps do
(
    ang = (180.0 / numSteps) * i

    /* Circular Calculations */
    xCircular = -1 * width/2.0 * cos(ang) --multiplied by -1 to flip horizontal
    yCircular = height * sin(ang)

    posC = [xCircular,yCircular,0] + [width/2.0,0,0]
    point pos:posC
)
```

Comment: There is no unique way of doing this mathematically (a term that applies to varying between *two* functions is homotopy).  Also it seems that you are really asking more of a programming question here.

Comment: I think this *could* be a really interesting question, but as hardmath noted, there are not enough restrictions to give a truly good answer.  Here are a couple questions to help hash out what you 'really' want: Do you want the points to be sampled at equal distances along the length of the curve, or at equal intervals along the $x$-axis?  Would you like the speed at which a point moves when the smoothness parameter is changed to be constant (for that point), or could it change?  Should the velocity of a point change smoothly (i.e., is it ok if a point suddenly changes speed of direction)? Etc.

Comment: I've corrected the post with new information.

Comment: Unfortunately you continue to frame the Question essentially in programming terms.  If you define your "Round Wave" as a function with fundamental period [-waveWidth/2,+waveWidth/2], and having maximum value waveWidth/2 at the midpoint of this period, then the "Inverted Round wave" can be expressed in terms of the "Round Wave" (shift the period forward by waveWidth/2 and subtract the function's value from waveWidth/2).  But you have even developed the mathematical formulas needed to express this idea symbolically, and the words I'm using may seem terribly complicated.